# Is it possible to pass values directly from Fragment to Custom View?

Tags: android

FragmentPickFloor.java

```
......

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnScan:
            if(spinFloor.performClick() && spinPartFloor.performClick()) {
                extras = new Bundle();
                spinFloorValue = spinFloor.getSelectedItem().toString();
                spinPartFloorValue = spinPartFloor.getSelectedItem().toString();
                extras.putString(Constants.FLOOR_KEY, spinFloorValue);
                extras.putString(Constants.FLOOR_PART_KEY, spinPartFloorValue);
                intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);

                FragmentCreator.fragmentTransactionSetup(new FragmentFloor(), getFragmentManager(), FragmentFloor.class.getSimpleName());
            }
                break;
    }
}
```

FragmentCreator.java

```
public static void fragmentTransactionSetup(Fragment fragment,
                                            FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                                            String tag) {

    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);

    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

FragmentFloor.java

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_floor, container, false);
}
```

TouchView.java

```
public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

        extras = ((MainActivity) getContext()).getIntent().getExtras();
        spinFloorValue = extras.getString(Constants.FLOOR_KEY);
        spinPartFloorValue = extras.getString(Constants.FLOOR_PART_KEY);
  }
```

TouchView display different backgrounds in dependency values you selected from spinners in FragmentPickFloor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indirectly yes.  You have to pass the bundle parameters to the fragment as arguments using the fragments `setArguments()` method and then pass the data to the custom view in `onCreateView()`.

When you create your Fragment, pass the values using the setArguments() method.

```
FragmentFloor fragment = new FragmentFloor();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(Constants.FLOOR_KEY, spinFloorValue);
args.putString(Constants.FLOOR_PART_KEY, spinPartFloorValue);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

Then in your fragment ...

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_floor, container, false);
    TouchView touchView = (TouchView)view.findViewById(R.id.touchView);

    touchView.setSpinFloorValue(getArguments().getString(Constants.FLOOR_KEY));
    touchView.setSpinPartFloorValue(getArguments().getString(Constants.FLOOR_PART_KEY));

    return view;
}
```

Alternatively you could try accessing the activity's bundle data directly from the fragment using `getActivity().getIntent()`

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_floor, container, false);
    TouchView touchView = (TouchView)view.findViewById(R.id.touchView);

    extras = ((MainActivity) getContext()).getIntent().getExtras();
    touchView.setSpinFloorValue(extras.getString(Constants.FLOOR_KEY));
    touchView.setSpinPartFloorValue(extras.getString(Constants.FLOOR_PART_KEY));

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I used your advice, but my values update after my custom view is dispayed.

Comment: In that case you'll need a way to propagate the values from the Activity => Fragment => Custom View.  There are several options:  You could use a **FragmentInteractionListener** like the ones generated by the *New Fragment Wizard*, an Event Bus like **Otto** or **RxJava**.  Research each one and determine which works best for you, given the amount of time involved in integrated each option.

Comment: Thank you. Now I trying with LayoutInflater.Factory

Comment: Solution was a very simple. We just need to create one function in custom view which is responsible for logic then call it after setters and finally use `touchView.invalidate()`